# My Component not re-render when the store is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactive-programming

I've googled but nothing has helped.
I know when in the redux I return the same object, the react Component not re-render. whatever I'm not mutating the store, I'm using connect from 'react-redux' and over other components works right

Thanks :D

```
//I'm updating a attribute value from this object: 
{name: 'some name', score: 0,}

//to 
{name: 'some name', score: 1,}

//just change the score 

//Component: 
class ListTeam extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ListContainer onNewTeam={this.props.onNewTeam}>
        {this.props.listTeam.map((item) =>
          <Item
            name={item.name}
            score={item.score}
            key={item.toString()}
          />
        )}
      </ListContainer>
    )
  }
}

const mapToProps = (store, props) => {
  return {
    listTeam: store.listTeam
  }
}

export default connect(mapToProps)(ListTeam)
```

REDUCER:

```
    case 'ADD_POINT':{
    let newstate = Object.assign({},state); //new state from current state
    let current = newstate.currentPlayer   //get current player 
    let listTeam = newstate.listTeam;  //getListTeam
    listTeam[current].score++; //+1 to score 

    return { 
        ...state,
        listTeam
    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing `connect()(ListTeam)`?

Comment: yes, in other components woks rigth but the score never is updated in the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you miss is that in `connect` provided by `react-redux`, it only does **shallow comparing** the current state with previous state. Since you only pass `currentPlayer` and `listTeam` from store to your component, and after the action `ADD_POINT`, the object `listTeam` is retained with all its keys unchanged, `connect` logic determined that no update should be made. Here is [a small example in redux's github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/585#issuecomment-315763033) issue thread that's closed to your implementation.

One simple solution is to clone your `listTeam` in store everytime you update, so that it will be recognized as new object:

```
   case 'ADD_POINT':{
    let newstate = Object.assign({},state); //new state from current state
    let current = newstate.currentPlayer   //get current player 
    let listTeam = newstate.listTeam;  //getListTeam
    listTeam[current].score++; //+1 to score 

    return { 
        ...state,
        listTeam: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listTeam)
    }
}
```

My simple Codesandbox for above solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/xjp77jpyro

You can also look into [Immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable) as it's recommended by Redux to handle immutable state.

Another solution is to customize the `connect` function to force it to recognize change in `list`: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#options-object. But I don't think you need to go that far.